How to delete images in i.sstatic.net that contains sensitive data
I posted a question a while ago and I realized only now that it contained sensitive information and I removed the link to it in the original post.
But I'm afraid I may get backlash if my employer realizes the image is still out there on i.sstatic.net.
Is there a way to delete an image from that website?

You should simply flag as the moderators can at least redact the revision without needing staff intervention, for deleting the image they'll pass it along to the staff.

I mean... backlash or not, knowing about a potential disclosure of sensitive data is something the employer should know, right? that's... kinda important. Mistakes happen, making another mistake by hiding it just continues the original mistake

Note that i.sstatic.net images are hosted in-house by Stack Exchange. They aren't on an external server like the old days with Imgur. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395024/334566 But of course there may be temporary cached copies of your image in Cloudflare for a little while...

Image hosting aside, it's almost certainly been copied to the various Stack Overflow leech sites out there.

So it seems, even though I'm trying to get rid of this image, I'm a fool to think that I can make it disappear completely.  It is not that sensitive for the effort it would require.  I'll try to edit the post with an image that masks the private info.
